# Select unique records ordered by date

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have 2 following models:

```rb
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base    
  attr_accessible :description, :deadline_on, :repeat    
  has_many   :scheduled_transactions    
end

class ScheduledTransaction < ActiveRecord::Base    
  attr_accessible :transaction_on, :description    
  belongs_to :schedule    
end
```

I want to find last scheduled transactions from each schedule. I know I can do:

```
Schedule.all.each do |schedule|
  schedule.scheduled_transactions.order(:transaction_on).last
end
```

but I want to optimize it and make a single database select.

I tried to construct Rails query:

```
ScheduledTransaction.select('DISTINCT(schedule_id), scheduled_transactions.*').order('transaction_on DESC')
```

which was translated into:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(schedule_id), scheduled_transactions.* FROM "scheduled_transactions" ORDER BY transaction_on DESC
```

but it doesn't give expected results. There are multiple rows with same schedule_id.

And my goal is to select list of scheduled transactions containing last scheduled transaction for each schedule. Any suggestions?

(PostgreSQL) 9.1.9

Comment: If you tag the question PostgreSQL please include the *actual SQL* generated by Rails and the result of running it by hand, your PostgreSQL version, any relevant error messages, etc.

Comment: Hi Craig, I have added required information to the question. Thanks for a tip.

Comment: The [DISTINCT ON](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) clause could be what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Guedes writes, you can use DISTINCT ON for this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (schedule_id) *
  FROM scheduled_transactions
  ORDER BY schedule_id, transaction_on DESC
```